# how to return to the start of a switch statement after case complete

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a console application in c# where I have to edit data inside a xml. This works so far I can get through id selection the dataset I want to edit and then edit single values. What I want to achieve is if the user gives an specific value after editing he/she should be able to go back a step back and edit other values of the same dataset.

For example: User edits the name of a customer with id 2 and wishes after saving the name to change adress. The application should be able to recognize the input from before and then just give the options of which the user can change the values again.

I tried calling the method inside the method but my application just finishes after saving the new value,

this is my code:

```
    bool inputTester = true;
    while (inputTester)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Welche Seiner Daten möchten Sie verändern?");
    Console.WriteLine("1) Für Vornamen");
    Console.WriteLine("2) Für Nachnamen");
    Console.WriteLine("3) für Adresse");
    Console.WriteLine("4) für Geburtsdatum");
    Console.WriteLine("5) für Bankdaten");

 
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie nun eine Option ein");
   
    switch (Console.ReadLine())
    {
        case "1":

            
                tgt = tempId;
                var name = tgt.Descendants("firstName").FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den neuen Vornamen ein");
                name.Value = Console.ReadLine();
                xDoc.Save(filepath);
                Console.WriteLine("Kunde gespeichert");
                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Möchten Sie weitere Daten dieses Kunden bearbeiten? Falls Ja drücken Sie 1");

                    if (Console.ReadLine().Equals(1))
                    
                        break;
                        break;
```

I tried to do it in case 1 with calling the method inside it.

EDIT: I tried to do it with the while advices but still the outcome is the same. The program just finishes and then closes itself.

I reduced my code to the minimal state posible to try it localy. I hope this is fine like this.

Comment: Add a while(true) before `Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie nun eine Option ein");` it has to wrap the switch too. And had an otion to break out of that loop. I will advice for [mre], and not complete code arrowing the code the the strict minimum will help solving and clarifying the issue.

Comment: And return make you leave the method and there is no going back. Store that true false in a variable and return it at the end.

Comment: I edited the code with while loop in my original post but the outcome is still the same like before...

Answer (score 0):

Place the Switch Statement in a While(true) Loop and when you want to go back to the start of the loop use the:

```
    Continue
```

statement, this will start the loop again.
And when you want to exit the loop just use:

```
    Break
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to simplify your issue in order to illustrate the error you made.

The requirement is :
The program will ask for "1" or "2" and sum it till you give up and type "Stop".

Your attempt looked like this : It wont loop and only ask once.

```
static int Count_Original()
{
    var num = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Original: How Many? (1/2)");
    switch (Console.ReadLine())
    {
        case "1":
            num += 1;
            return num;

        case "2":
            num += 2;
            return num;
    }
    return num;
}
```

If we had a loop: It will still not loop as the return make us quit the method.

```
static int Count_Loop()
{
    var num = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loop: How Many? (1/2)");
        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1":
                num += 1;
                return num;

            case "2":
                num += 2;
                return num;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Simply removing the return won't fix it, we are now trap in the loop.

```
static int Count_Trap()
{
    var num = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trap: How Many? (1/2)");
        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1":
                num += 1;
                break;

            case "2":
                num += 2;
                break;

            default: // I didn't understand the input. Let me ask again.
                break;
        }
    };
    return num; // Never reach
}
```

The final version will look like this:

- A break out option using return
- a default in case we didn't type a valid option.

```
static int Count_Fix()
{
    var num = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fix: How Many? (1/2)");
        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "Stop": // Breakout condition, we are leaving
                return num;

            case "1":
                num += 1;
                break;

            case "2":
                num += 2;
                break;

            default: // I didn't understand the input. Let me ask again.
                break;
        }
    };
    return num;
}
```

Finally if you wan't to have some conditional loop back or exit you can do it with a if/else:

```
static int Count_Fix()
{
    var num = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fix: How Many? (1/2)");
        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {

            case "1":
                num += 1;
                break;

            case "2":
                num += 2;
                if (num % 2 == 0) break; // conditional go back or exit
                else return num; // exit

            default: // I didn't understand the input. Let me ask again.
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hey I had edited my code now with breaks, but if I understand you correctly you give a case where the user can stop the loop. But what I want is to decide this inside one case this time case 1 if he should go back to the start of the loop/Switch or not. But I am still stuck with the application just finishing.

Comment: Ok, how about I make the stop option only work for Add number. Is that variation enought to illustrate a conditional loop back?

Comment: I think I have an idea on how to make it stop haha I just can not seem to get it back to where it says: Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben Sie nun eine Option ein");

Comment: I added a block with no Leaver option.
All case a significative and have an effect. in order to leave one must Choose 2 and end with odd number. I think it's should be clear enought to be adapt to your code.